# How to open a ".pyc" file with Pycharm?

Tags: python, file, pycharm

I was programming some code in pycharm and I don't know how it came out and saved like this: `Eq_FD.cpython-39.pyc`. Whereas before it was just `Eq_FD`. When I tried to open it again in pycharm it was full of characters so that I can't understand what is written. Looks to me like it's in binary language or something different. Is there a way to recover the file?

Comment: [What is a PYC file?](https://docs.fileformat.com/executable/pyc/)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal The question should probably be closed as a duplicate of the final link in the canonical chain, e.g. [Why does Python compile modules but not the script being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268017/why-does-python-compile-modules-but-not-the-script-being-run) -- it's rarely a good idea to close a question as a duplicate of another duplicate question.

Comment: @TylerH I spefically chose that question as I feel the original question and answer don't really explain **what** a PYC file is.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open .pyc file becuase it is already python interpreter compiled file so that's why it is shows only binary code. So, you have to find your .py file for viewing your code